# [Wordress][ACF] Создание нового ACF поля: Метки / Маркеры на рисунке?

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте, может кто знает или даже сталкивался с созданием нового поля для плагина ACF (Wordpress), где былабы возможность добавления метки / маркера на рисунке.

Логика структуры поля:

- Рисунок:

  - Метки:

    - Метка:

      - Уникальный ID
      - Имя
      - Координата Х
      - Координата Y

Может ктото имеет очень похожее решение?

Дополнительная инфо: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/create-image-mapperhotspot-with-repeater/

Comment: Есть готовые решения, не привязанные к плагину ACF. Интересует?

Comment: Да, конечно. Будет интересно всё увидеть

Comment: Посмотрите небольшую подборку  https://pluginspress.com/tag/hotspot/

Comment: Я обычно использую этот - https://codecanyon.net/item/image-map-hotspot-wordpress-plugin/5586825. Он самый нормальный и есть кеш человеческий

Comment: Спасибо ;) Присмотрюсь поближе